# Best practice for python module with thousands of classes in one file

Tags: python

I have a generated python module file with thousands of data classes, size 6MB.

These classes are generated from database structure, so I can not reduce them or not provide them with my module.

This module cause two main problem:

1. Very slow importing
2. Damage performance of IDE

the number of classes I currently used in this module is less than 30, but I have to provide all of them in my module since other users may use some of them.

My current code looks like:

`foo.py`:

```py
from .models import ClassA, ClassB


class Foo():

    def __init__(slef):
        self.a = ClassA()
        self.b = ClassB()
```

`__init__.py` :

```
from .foo import Foo
from . import models
```

What's the right way to organize the classes in the module?

Comment: The most obvious answer is to reduce the number of classes by a couple of orders of magnitude.

Comment: Well, this sound like compulsive class hoarding.You generate what you need for your project. You don't keep code just in case it is need at some point in time that never comes.

Comment: I assume "thounds" is "thousands"? Also if it's generated source for all possible configurations of something, perhaps you could build classes dynamically as needed instead of hard-coding all of them ahead of time?

Comment: @jwal, the classes are generated from database structure, so I can not modify them and all of them may be useful for some user.

Comment: @CrazyChucky, These classes are acutally generated from dynamic class from `sqlalchemy's reflect`, I can use them dynamically but IDE won't and it is hard for other end-users to use them.

Comment: Is it possible they could at least be organized into more than one file?

Comment: @CrazyChucky, Yes I could, but will this help? I'm not sure a huge file vs. thousands of file which is worse.

Comment: Well I dunno about thousands of files. But maybe four or five or so? Each one would at least be faster and easier to open. Not to mention, if they could be divided in some predictable way, it would make it easier for users to find what they're looking for. Keep in mind that even `from ___ import ___` still reads/executes the *entire file*, even though it only binds the specified name(s) into the current namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the classes available in one module without having to import them ***all*** into another module where you intend to use them.

Say "6megModule.py" contains classes class1..class9999

```
from 6megModule import class1, class2, class3
```

If you can give more details about how you have designed your classes others may be able to help with structuring them, is there a good reason for having so many classes? Will your users be able to wade through such a massive amount to find and use the classes they actually need?

Comment: Thanks, I have post my current code structure in question.